# Azure alerting rule for poison queue count

Tags: azure, queue, azure-webjobs, poison-queue

In a pervious project I have managed to setup a Alert rule that looks at poison queue message count and alerts using a webhook into slack when something is in the queue (once per day).

I was trying to find where this exists in Azure as it looks like things have moved around. If this is not a feature provided by azure could you give guidance on what's the best route in implementing something similar.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I was trying to find where this exists in Azure as it looks like things have moved around. If this is not a feature provided by azure could you give guidance on what's the best route in implementing something similar.

As far as I know, currently there is no a feature provided by azure to send the a alert rule to check the poison queue count.

You need write you own logic to achieve this requirement.

I suggest you could considerusing webjob/azure function timer trigger or queue trigger.

If you want to check the poison count every 5 minutes(for example), you could choose [timer trigger](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions#timertrigger).

Then in the timer trigger method, you could use [ApproximateMessageCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueue.approximatemessagecount?view=azurestorage-8.1.3) method to get the queue messages' count.

At last, you could use sendgrid to send the notification email to special account.

Codes:

```
        //get the storage account from the connection string
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

        //instantiate the client
        CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();

        CloudQueue q = queueClient.GetQueueReference("queue-poison");
        q.FetchAttributes();
        var qCnt = q.ApproximateMessageCount;
```

If you want to get the count when the new queue message has added into the poison queue. You could choose [queue trigger](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Queues). The codes is as same as the timer trigger, just change the parameters.